# What is the word for someone who hates confrontation?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, pejorative-language

Such a person doesn't mind losing or winning; however, they dislike having to experience resistance/confrontation.  To clarify, such a person does not necessarily "fear" confrontation but thinks confrontation is **too much of a hassle**.

Let's make a point that **finds confrontation too much of a hassle** is the primary meaning.

— A clarifying treat for those who get it; otherwise, insightful nonetheless:

"If I don't have to do it, I won't.  If I have to do it, I'll make it quick."

Comment: "hates" confrontation or "fears" confrontation??

Comment: Apparently, "almost-everyone-in-my-school". :)

Comment: Hmmm... Coward sprang to mind from you question title. It still marginally applies, as one definition for coward is a lack of courage to endure dangerous or unpleasant things. But there are probably more applicable terms.

Comment: A grown and experienced person doesn't have any feelings for confrontation, neither fear nor joy. Also, hate and dislike come from negative feelings associated with the confrontation, so it's still fear, albeit less concentrated. Confronting or getting confronted by someone a meaningful number of times will cause this hate and dislike to disappear, so it's a temporary condition and the person shouldn't be named anything but inexperienced.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Conflict-averse" is the term we use for this in the human services professions.

Comment: Could you provide any references or quotes to back up your answer? Thank you.

Comment: +1 this is definitely the phrase that leaped to mind when I saw this question.

Answer (score 20):

I think the easiest word is non-confrontational.

I would also suggest the following:

- carefree
- nonchalant
- indifferent

Comment: It was as simple as tacking a "non" to it; whenever English isn't complicated it is just straight-forward :b

Comment: Non-confrontational sounds more accurate than carefree or indifferent. A person could be be carefree or indifferent but still be confrontational.

Comment: Is non-confrontational  a common usage word?

Comment: @Keni - the idea of being carefree is not caring.  If you don't care what would you be confrontational about?  Indifferent is the same thing.

Comment: @Jack - very very common.  Especially in speech.

Comment: @user2738698, non-confrontational is what you are looking for.  "carefree", "nonchalant" and "indifferent" don't necessarily mean the same as non-confrontational.

Comment: @RyeBread - I feel someone could be a carefree person and still be passionate enough about a particular issue to want to be confrontational about it. I think I am that type of person, hence the hesitation to use non-confrontational interchangeably with carefree and nonchalant.

Answer (score 2):

Consider [**placid**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/placid), [**unconfrontational**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unconfrontational), and [**easygoing**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/easygoing).

> [**placid**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Placid): indisturbed by tumult or disorder; calm.
>
> [**unconfrontational**](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080903200741AAvB6rT): not confrontational.

Comment: Dead link. (15char)

Comment: The link is misspelled with an 'm' where there should be an 'n'. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conciliating

Comment: Great word to add to my vocabulary. Thanks, Elian!

Comment: While this is a good answer, it seems to add meaning on top of what was requested. Someone who dislikes conflict does not necessarily take action to lessen conflict.

Comment: I agree with @MichaelMior this is not really what the question was.  A conciliatory person is a peacemaker.  Someone who is uniting two sides that are fighting possibly.  So they do get involved in conflict, but as "counselor".

Comment: Unfortunately, the change in definition no longer makes this word as valid as it was before :b

Answer (score 2):

You could call that person "agreeable" or "passive"? - as in, they will go along with what another person wants, whether they want to really or not, in order to avoid confrontation.

Answer (score 2):

I have always used the word **[amiable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amiable)**:

> **a·mi·a·ble**  [**ey**-mee-*uh*-b *uh* l]
>
> ***adjective***
>
> 1. having or showing pleasant, good-natured personal qualities; affable: *an amiable disposition.*
> 2. friendly; sociable: *an amiable greeting; an amiable gathering.*
> 3. agreeable; willing to accept the wishes, decisions, or suggestions of another or others.

It's ***antonyms*** would definitely describe one that is confrontational:

> **1.** rude. **2.** unfriendly, hostile.

Answer (score 2):

When this creates an obstacle to function or communication, the verbiage in the DSM of the APA is 'avoidant' as in the "Avoidant Personality Disorder", or the paradoxical "Avoidant Attachment".

It differs from conflict-aversion as the basis of a Social Phobia, in that the person avoiding does it habitually, or in the spirit of excessive detachment, not out of (aware) fear.

(That is why this almost always ends up as an Axis II thing, and not a primary disorder.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest we coin "anticonfrontationalist"

Comment: Please provide a definition; it may very well fit the word I seek and checks may be shuffled around, if you know what I mean ;D

Comment: how about profrontation-alist

Answer (score 0):

A couple that spring to mind, depending on context.

**Compliant**: disposed to agree with others or obey rules, especially to an excessive degree.  Similarly, acquiescent, docile.  These indicate someone who will avoid confrontation by agreeing with something disagreeable.

**Passive-resistance** (or resistor): is the practice of achieving goals ... without using violence.  This is a better fit for someone who still disagrees with the disagreeable thing, but wishes to avoid confrontation while bringing about change.

Answer (score -1):

*Peaceable* refers to a person who likes to be left in peace, but doesn't imply weakness.

Answer (score -1):

*Evasive*. Or *non-confrontational*. Whatever works!

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. On this and other sites in the Stack Exchange network, we are expected to provide not merely an answer, but an explanation of the answer, with links to suitable references. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.